# keyword tags in chm hhk

Tags: chm, chmcmd

I'm currently looking examining binary index building for CHM, but I noticed that some hhk's from sample projects (e.g. Sphinx generated) have a "keyword" tag that does not seem documented in [chmspec](http://www.nongnu.org/chmspec/latest/Sitemap.html). chmspec does allude that the keyword exists though.

Is the "keyword" tag in this context just an alias for the (First?) "name" tag?

From e.g. ags (https://github.com/adventuregamestudio/ags-manual/issues/14) Their chmfiles indeed have hhks with this inside.

```
LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
        <param name="Keyword" value="Functions that return a value">
        <param name="See Also" value="Functions that return a value">
    </OBJECT>
    <UL> <LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
        <param name="Keyword" value="Scripting Tutorial">
        <param name="Local" value="ScriptingTutorialPart1.html#index-7">
    </OBJECT>
    </UL><LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
        <param name="Keyword" value="Game / Global functions">
        <param name="Local" value="Game.html#index-0">
    </OBJECT>
    <UL> <LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
        <param name="Keyword" value="AbortGame">
        <param name="Local" value="Game.html#index-1"> ...
```

Comment: Please add a short code example (MS Index Sitemap format) from your *.hhk sample project file to your question.

Comment: Done. Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short story - I don't know exactly why `name="Keyword"` is used for `name="Name"` here. It seems as if both attributes are usable but this is not documented. I tend to `name="Keyword"` but at this time I use `name="Name"`.

You know - creating a good index for HTMLHelp files (CHM) is time consuming and requires a lot of work. Since users are increasingly using the full text search (or Google), I rarely create a complex index. I am using the following syntax (sitemap snippet) with attribute `name="Name"`:

```html
<LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
    <param name="Name" value="Flowers">
    <param name="Local" value="Garden/flowers.htm">
    </OBJECT>
```

It has been a long time ago but I remember having seen the attribute `name="Keyword"` before. After some searching, my memory was back.

If you convert a WinHelp Project to HTMLHelp with HTMLHelp Workshop (HHW) you get these attributes generated in the index (I tried again this old stuff).

```html
<LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
    <param name="Keyword" value="Adresse">
    <param name="Name" value="RS485-Bus durchsuchen">
    <param name="Local" value="html/sens04xe.htm">
    </OBJECT>
<LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
    <param name="Keyword" value="Baudrate">
    <param name="Name" value="Konfiguration der PC-Schnittstelle">
    <param name="Local" value="html/sens04xd.htm">
    <param name="Name" value="RS485-Interface des Transmitters">
    <param name="Local" value="html/sens04xh.htm">
    </OBJECT>
```

Duplicate node info happens also often when using HHW for indexing. Of course I'm using FAR HTML's feature **Auto-Normalize HHK Files** in this case resulting in:

```html
<LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
    <param name="Name" value="Adresse">
    <param name="Local" value="html/sens04xe.htm">
    </OBJECT>
<LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
    <param name="Name" value="Baudrate">
    <param name="Name" value="Konfiguration der PC-Schnittstelle">
    <param name="Local" value="html/sens04xd.htm">
    <param name="Name" value="RS485-Interface des Transmitters">
    <param name="Local" value="html/sens04xh.htm">
    </OBJECT>
```

Both *.hhk variants are compiled into a CHM without errors. There is no difference for the user to see. Following screenshot (FAR HTML GUI) shows the index editor dialog after normalizing. Only keywords like e.g. "Baudraute" assigned to two topics have a red star now. Before the normalization all keywords had a red star.

[image: Screenshot of editing my *.hhk file]

When editing HHK files edited by HHW (as mentiones above) you may see many single folders with a single popup item. These can be reduced and simplified to a single non-popup entry. The only reason you would want to preserve this duplicate information is if you use Information Types -- a HTMLHelp 1.x feature that was never properly completed anyway. It's  recommended that you always Normalizing HHK Indexes if you have the chance. It reduces file size and complexity with no visible change for the user at run-time.

I tried to find some documentation in a book from 1997 "Official Microsoft HTMLHelp Authoring Kit" but nothing found.

**Additional information:**

***HTML inline keywords***

In an HTMLHelp project, keywords for the index can be integrated as meta statements in the <head> section using an undocumented function. The keywords specified in this way are included in the index in a compiled help system.

See: http://www.help-info.de/en/KIT/Creating_Index/create_index.htm#UndocumentedIndex

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>How one grows trees </title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="tree, hole">
  <meta name="MS-HKWD" content="oak">
  <meta name="MS-HKWD" content="beech">
  <meta name="MS-HKWD" content="water">
  <meta name="MS-HAID" content="botany">
  <link href="../design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

***Sphinx source code for builders HTMLHelp***

Seems `name="Keyword"` to be hard coded here (I don't deepened further for `name="Name"` cases):

https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/builders/htmlhelp.py

Comment: Thank you. You confirm my suspicions. Thank you also for the inline keyword help, I don't implement that in the chmcmd compiler either. (yet). I'll see if I can warn on unnormalized indexes.

Comment: @Marco Please note when using inline keywords a round trip decompile <=> compile is not working. The keywords are stripped from the HTML files.