# Index is empty in a chm file compiled with Microsoft HTML Help Workshop

Tags: html, compilation, chm, tableofcontents, html-help-workshop

I am working with Microsoft Html Help Workshop and trying to build a help project which has more than 19k help files including html, css, png etc. I built an hhp file as new.hhp and put folllowing lines in it

```
  [OPTIONS]
     Auto Index=Yes
     Auto TOC=9
     Compatibility=1.1 or later
     Compiled file=new.chm
     Default Window=TriPane
     Default topic=HomePage.htm
     Display compile progress=Yes
     Error log file=log.log
     Full-text search=Yes
     Index file=Index.hhk
     Language=0x409 English (United States)
   [WINDOWS]
     TriPane="new",,"Index.hhk",,"HomePage.htm",,,,,0xe2520,255,0x304e,[0,0,800,600],,,,,2,,0
   [FILES]
```

I checked the option to create a binary index as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqE2p.png).

I checked the option for including keywords as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t586d.png).

I compiled it as new.chm and it searches for all the required topics but index file is empty as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKlxP.png).

I also checked the index.hhk file and it is empty as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pSMH.png) too..

Its not possible for me to include keywords manually for 19k files. What should I do to so that keywords from all html files add to index and I don't get the empty index ?
Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some info. Give a short comment on my answer when done.(1) Was there really no Help Authoring Tool used in 2008 and was only the HTMLHelp Workshop used? (2) Are the 19000 (really?) HTML files still the original files used at that time?
(3) Does the original CHM file still exist? (4) How big is this file (MB)? (5) Attach an HTML example (<head> section) of one of your HTML files.

Comment: What about my request (see my questions above) to add some information? A first idea related to my questions here is, if the previous CHM still exists the old index.hhk can be decompiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer - there is **no automated way**!

The keywords are assigned manually to the topics with Microsoft HTMLHelp Workshop. Please keep in mind - the technical development for CHM files and the HTMLHelp Workshop is 25 years old. But there is no real alternative under Windows even today, unfortunately.

You probably expect from ***Include keywords from HTML files*** option the keywords (HTML syntax e.g.: `<meta name="keywords" content="CSS, Script">`) to be integrated automatically. But keywords for CHM are thought of differently here and something special (e.g. `<meta Name="MS-HKWD" content="keyword">`). I can't remember but maybe the HTML tag `keywords` didn't exist at that time (25 years ago).

You know, a single word index is quite familiar to everyone, having been employed in the back of reference and trade books practically since the beginning of print. But creating a good index for HTMLHelp files (CHM) is time consuming and requires a lot of work. Since users are increasingly using the full text search of CHM Viewer (or Google), I rarely create a complex index nowadays.

(1) You may want to create the `index.hhk` file by yourself writing a script e.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta name="generator" content="Microsoft&reg; HTML Help Workshop 4.1">
<!-- Sitemap 1.0 -->
</head>
<body>
<OBJECT type="text/site properties">
</OBJECT>
<UL>
    <LI><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
            <param name="Name" value="Flowers">
            <param name="Name" value="Flowers">
            <param name="Local" value="Garden/flowers.htm">
         </OBJECT>
    <LI><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
            <param name="Name" value="Garden">
            <param name="Name" value="Garden">
            <param name="Local" value="Garden/Garden.htm">
         </OBJECT>
    <LI><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
            <param name="Name" value="How one grows trees">
            <param name="Name" value="How one grows trees">
            <param name="Local" value="Garden/tree.htm">
         </OBJECT>
</UL>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

(2) You may want to use a freeware tool like FAR HTML (recommended using the Wizard!):

Please note - freeware tools like [FAR HTML](https://www.help-info.de/download.html) are using the complete contents of a  tag to generate a index and don't output single words for index of help files.

[image]

(3) You can find more information with additional details at:

- Please read old stuff from my site: [Welcome to KIT's online help!](https://www.help-info.de/en/KIT/)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53132643/1981088

Comment: I tried to add multiple keywords in index using KIT's link you provided, but whenever I start the KIT, it shows an message box to visit the site for its latest version even if I have downloaded the latest version provided on site. After pressing ok, it shows the windows version it supports exluding Windows 10. Also, it was taking more than 1 hr.  to search keyword without completing the task. I think the product is outdated. Can you help me some other way?

Comment: @Rashmi - yes, KIT is old stuff and outdated. The information was intended for the particularities of index keywords using HTMLHelp Workshop as mentioned in my answer - see also: [Making index with an undocumented function](https://www.help-info.de/en/KIT/Creating_Index/create_index.htm#UndocumentedIndex).

Comment: I got the desired results using FAR HTML. Thanks for your help.